# Trigger has no Binding property

Tags: wpf, binding, controltemplate

During i reading up on WPF i have run into a problem trying to create a binding on the Trigger in a template, used to create an image button.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ToolbarButtonHover" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Name="backgroundGrid">
        <Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Img}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"></Image>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="backgroundGrid" Property="Background" Value="#007ACC" />
        </Trigger>
        <!--Error: The property 'Binding' was not found in type Trigger-->
        <Trigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="backgroundGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Results in the Error `The property 'Binding' was not found in type Trigger`, more specifically its the line 
   `<Trigger Binding="{ Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">`That generates it.

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 10):

Probably because there is no Binding property on the Trigger class [as you can see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger_properties.aspx).

You probably are looking for a [DataTrigger](http://www.bing.com/search?q=DataTrigger%20class&go=Submit&qs=ds&form=QBRE).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ToolbarButtonHover" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Name="backgroundGrid">
        <Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Img}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"></Image>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="backgroundGrid" Property="Background" Value="#007ACC" />
        </Trigger>
        <!--Look below, DataTrigger -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="backgroundGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```